# how to " fix Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in " for php?

Tags: javascript, php

there is an error -> 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/document/allstudent/index.php on line 35

```
<?php
          $url=@$_GET["url"];
            switch ($url) {
              case 'kayit':
                if ($_POST) {
                  $user=trim(strip_tags($_POST["user"]));
                  $password=trim(strip_tags($_POST["password"]));
                  $email=trim(strip_tags($_POST["email"]));
                  $date= date("d/m/y");

                    **if((empty($user) or empty($password) or empty($email)){

                      echo 'Hata oluştu.Tüm alanları doldurunuz!';
                      header("refresh:2;index.php?url=kayit");
                   }

                  else{
                        $sql = mysql_query("insert into allstudent" );
                  }**


                }else{
                  echo '<form action="" method="post">
                <span>User</span>
                <span><input type="text" name="user" class="input" </span>
                <span>Password</span>
                <span><input type="password" name="password" class="input"</span>
                <span>Email</span>
                <span><input type="text" name="email" class="input"</span>
                <span><input type="submit" value="kayit ol"</span>     

                </form>';}
                break;
```

Comment: By looking why is at said part a `{`. I don't know how this error message can't be understood.

Comment: for the second if statement , i got "{" error , i will cry because i did not find it. Help!

Comment: Look for pair of parenthesis. Is there missing close `)` right before `{`?

Comment: You better use IDE for syntax highlighting.

Comment: You forgot a `}` before the first `else`.

Comment: Did you try to research similar problems or read the error and try to solve it?...

Comment: @Dunois what do u mean , man?

Comment: @Anonymous2 there is also } there.

Comment: @legolas. I just commented what's your problem with the line you said and also posted an answer. Look what is missing.

Answer (score 1):

Look for this:

```
if((empty($user) or empty($password) or empty($email)){
   ^                                                 ^
 opened an extra '('                             missing ')'
```

You are missing a closing parenthesis since you began with **TWO** opening `(`.

Is it obviously?
You need a meticulous attention on how many parenthesis you have in your IF Statement...

Comment: You're welcome. This is really trick since PHP expects closing parenthesis where it accusing unexpected '{' and really needs a meticulous attention

Answer (score 0):

```
switch ($url) {
```

is never closed

Add an } after

```
 </form>';}
 break;
}
```

Comment: you are correct, but it is because of forgotten "}" . correct answer is above which is bcesars comment.